# histogram + frequention polygon

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, statistics

This is my code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds,snakes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=1*\textwidth,
height=8cm,
ymin=0,
ymax=7,
title=Histogram lichaamslengte,
ybar interval,
xticklabel={[\pgfmathprintnumber\tick--\pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick [}],
\addplot+[hist={bins=4, data max=12,data min=0}]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 10\\ 4\\ 5\\ 7\\ 10\\ 9\\ 8\\ 9\\ 9\\ 11\\
};
\end{axis}
\tkzDefPoints{2.1/2.75/A, 4.3/3.7/B, 6.7/1.8/C, 9/5.5/D}
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,D)
\tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
\tkzDrawSegment(B,C)
\tkzDrawSegment(C,D) 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I've managed to make the histogram, but I also want a frequention polygon on top of the histogram. 
The solution that I've found is not good at all, because, it's not scalable. So my question is, how can I make this polygon, that is using the class-middles. If possible, automatically. Thanks!

[image: histogram + frequention polygon]

Comment: Shouldn't it be “frequency polygon"?

Comment: yes, but my native language isn't English ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can draw the histogram plot twice, once as `ybar interval` as in your example, and the second time as `sharp plot`.

In order to visualize a `hist` plot in a different way, one can redefine the `handler` style within the options for `hist`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds,snakes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=1*\textwidth,
height=8cm,
ymin=0,
ymax=7,
title=Histogram lichaamslengte,
ybar interval,
xticklabel={[\pgfmathprintnumber\tick--\pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick [}],
\addplot+[hist={bins=4, data max=12,data min=0}]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 10\\ 4\\ 5\\ 7\\ 10\\ 9\\ 8\\ 9\\ 9\\ 11\\
};

\addplot[
    %
    % there seems to be a bug in pgfplots which would shift the two
    % 'hist' plots as if both were bar plots.
    % This is one possible work-around:
    forget plot,
    %
mark=*,
    hist={bins=4, data max=12,data min=0,
        % this here should *not* become an ybar interval:
        handler/.style={sharp plot},intervals=false,
    },
    %
    % .. but since the other plot is shown with intervals, we should
    % shift this here accordingly:
    shift={(axis direction cs:1.5,0)},
]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 10\\ 4\\ 5\\ 7\\ 10\\ 9\\ 8\\ 9\\ 9\\ 11\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

This experiment revealed to me that there is room for improvements:

1. without `forget plot`, `pgfplots` assumes that there are two bar plots and makes "both" smaller. This is a bug; `forget plot` is one possible workaround (a different one would be to modify `bar interval width` and `bar interval shift` for the *first* plot). I will take a todo note for `pgfplots`; this will become unnecessary eventually.
2. one has to enter `interval=false` although it is clear from the context that `sharp plot` needs no interval. I will take a todo note for `pgfplots`; this will become unnecessary eventually.

I will check the histogram handler and fix bugs and usability issues around it eventually (probably the next version of `pgfplots`).

Answer (score 1):

As a partial answer, by using

```
xmin=0,xmax=12,name=border,
```

inside the xaxis definition you can create scalable coordinates, for example

```
\coordinate (Y) at ($.143*(border.north) - .143*(border.south)$);
\coordinate (A) at ($(border.south west)!.125!(border.south east) + 3*(Y)$);
```

where (Y) is the length of one unit of vertical change.  However, you still need to calculate the histogram values (again) or find out where Tikz put them.

Comment: I will give it a try, but I would be great if their was an option like:
frequencypolygon=true;
frequencypolygon=false;

Comment: I had to look up frequency polygon in Wikipedia to even know what the heck it was supposed to be.  It isn't really a polygon.  I would call it a frequency line graph (not to be confused with a line chart).

Comment: In fact it is a polygon, since it should be drawn like this:
http://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/frequency-polygon.html
and that results in a polygon, because the x-axe connects the begin and end point.

Comment: I know it is called a polygon, but a polygon is a closed figure; that is, the first point is the same as the last point.  THAT, is a line graph (or polyline).

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=1*\textwidth,
height=9cm,
xmin=-1,xmax=13,
ymin=0, ymax=7,
title=Histogram lichaamslengte,
ybar interval,
xticklabel={[\pgfmathprintnumber\tick;\pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick [}],
\addplot+[hist={bins=4, data max=12,data min=0}]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 10\\ 4\\ 5\\ 7\\ 10\\ 9\\ 8\\ 9\\ 9\\ 11\\
};
\addplot[sharp plot,mark=square]
coordinates
{(1.5,3) (4.5,4) (7.5,2) (10.5,6)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answering your own questions feels like Mr Beam sending cards to himself. But anyway, thanks for the answers. After looking in the pgf manual, the simples way for me is adding a plot with the coördinates, it's scalable, and doesn't take that much time.

Resulting in:

[image: solution]